# Sets composed of arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory

Take a generalized arithmetic progression (GAP)

$$P_{n} = \lbrace a + x_{1}r_{1} + x_{2}r_{2} + \ldots + x_{n}r_{n} | 0\leq x_{i} < k_{i} \rbrace = \lbrace a + \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}r_{i} | 0\leq x_{i} < k_{i} \rbrace$$

Where $k_{i}$ is the length of the progression, $r_{i}$ the common difference, $x_{i}$ the independent variable, and $a$ is the initial term (with $k_{i}, r_{i}, x_{i}, a \in \mathbb{Z}$). Considering this as a function of the natural numbers: $\alpha \colon \mathbb{N^{0}} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{N^{0}} = \lbrace 0,1,2,... \rbrace$

$$\alpha(x) = a + \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}r_{i}$$

I considered the initial definition of a GAP and thought that the above function could be generalized even further to include all sets $A$ which can be defined entirely by a set of arithmetic progressions

$$A = \lbrace a_{1}+x_{1}r_{1}, a_{2}+x_{2}r_{2},\ldots,...a_{n}+x_{n}r_{n} | 0\leq x_{i} < k_{i} \rbrace $$

I again considered this as a function of the natural numbers, and came up with

$$\alpha(x, i) = a_{i}+x_{i}r_{i}$$

Are these two functions accurate representations of the former definitions? Is there anything to be gained from viewing these sets of arithmetic progressions as functions, or is this simply trivial?

Comment: The 2nd display - the left side seems to be a function of $i$, the right side is independent of $i$ - how does that work?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is fixed. 

Comment: The 2nd display again - it is not clear exactly how you define your function. ($x$ does not appear in the right-hand side, but the $x_i$ do.)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether the subscript $i$ should be there or not in the 2nd and 4th display, because $x_{i}$ is the variable but the $i$ alone is also significant and does change.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas about this?